# Asynchronously update asp.net repeater as and when data changes

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, ajax, mvvm

I want an asp.net repeater control to update by itself as and when the actual data that it's pointing to, gets updated. I'm not looking for a solution where a button click happens and each time repeater(which is inside an updatepanel) is bound to a datasource.

Ex: In my page load, I have this

```
Page_Load(){
   myRepeater.DataSource = ListOfStringObj;
   myRepeater.DataBind();
}
```

Now, if at some point ListOfStringObj gets updated, then the repeater should reflect the changes without explicitly binding it again to the datasource.
Is this even possible? I'm not particular about repeater control here, it can be a gridview as well. If not can anyone please explain?

PS: Something of this sort is possible using Knockout js, which is based on MVVM

Thanks,
Sharath

Comment: How and when is `ListOfStringObj` updated? If you don't know this you need to keep checking for changes, which is probably not be a good solution...

Comment: ListOfStringObj is updated somewhere within my code, say, a click event or something. But, I don't want to again assign the datasource and call DataBind(). The repeater should automatically update.

Answer (score 1):

I hope this MVVM for ASP.NET will help you to achieve this: [asp.net MVVM](http://aspnetmvvm.codeplex.com/)